# setparent not working correctly in placing vb6 form in vb .net form

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, interop, vb6-migration

I have a large vb6 app that I turned into a dll so I could run it from vb .net. When I run the vb6 & .net projects in debug everything works fine. If I open the forms non modally everything works fine all the time.

However when I compile the vb6 into a dll the vb6 forms are not being placed in the .Net container form when I open them modally (non modal is OK). The vb6 form just sits in the upper left of the screen.

I came up with this solution based on an [article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19368/Embedding-of-VB6-form-in-NET-applications) by Eduardo Campano on embedding vb6 forms in .Net applications from July 2007. Great article and a good idea if you have a million lines of code to convert to .net like I do.

I have sample code but don't see how to upload it to the forum.

The code for loading the vb6 into the container is from the container load event in .net:

```
 SetParent(mintFormHandle, Me.Handle.ToInt32)
 SendMessage(Me.Handle.ToInt32, WM_NCACTIVATE, 1, 0)
 SetForegroundWindow(Me.Handle.ToInt32)
 LockWindowUpdate(0)
```

Comment: I edited a link to the article into your question - I assume it is the right article? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19368/Embedding-of-VB6-form-in-NET-applications